# Formation sketching; trouble with sampling unit optimization

Tags: algorithms

I'm looking for assistance in understanding a concise portion of a paper that involves a quadratic equation, so that I can properly implement it.

There are 2 versions of the paper. Each paper utilizes a slightly different quadratic form to achieve the same goal, but I've found success with neither. Here are the papers (along with the corresponding sections) in question:

http://graphics.cs.uh.edu/website/satelliteLinks/GI2011_formationSketching_preprint.pdf
(Section 3.6)

http://graphics.cs.uh.edu/website/satelliteLinks/2011_CGA-crowd-formation-generation-preprint.pdf
(Section 'Boundary sketches'. The quadratic can be found on page 18)

My math expertise is limited. I am primarily confused when I am asked to solve the quadratic for a single value, since I'm only aware of how to solve quadratic equations in a way that there are 2 possible solutions. How do I solve the quadratic in a way that I would find a single value for *b* in the context of the application?

**EDIT**: Here are the equations and a simple description:

Given an arbitrary shape and an arbitrary integer "sampling unit", the sampling unit is used to both place points along the boundary of the shape, as well as to employ a flood fill algorithm to fill the rest of the shape, generating a formation for a group of AI agents $n$. Solving either quadratic below will yield a more optimized/desired boundary point count $b$, which is then used to compute a more optimized sampling unit for a more realistic formation based on the number of agents $n$.

*I'm looking to understand how to properly solve for* $b$.

$b$ = Desired number of boundary agents
$n$ = Number of AI agents

*Version 1*:

$b{}'$ = Number of points *on* the boundary of the initial formation
$f{}'$ = Number of points *inside* the boundary of the initial formation

$b^{2}+(2\times (n+\frac{\sqrt{f{}'}}{b{}'}))\times b +n^{2} = 0$

*Version 2*:

$r$ = Ratio between boundary points and inside points of the initial formation

$b^{2}+r^{^2}\times b-r^{2}\times n=0$

**NOTE**: I'm aware this may not be the right place for this question. I'd appreciate references to any other more appropriate places.

Comment: Can you write down the equations?

Comment: Here's a video for additional context. I need more rep to post additional links in my question: https://youtu.be/VmKD_by9rAQ?t=1m39s

Comment: Assuming that all your parameters are positive, that they should because they are numbers, your first equation have complex solutions: $[b = - n - \sqrt{2}\,i\,f^{1/4}, b = \sqrt{2}\,i\,f^{1/4} - n]$. For your second equation there is a root that is always negative, then you should pick the other one.

Comment: I'll give that a shot and return soon.

Comment: I wasn't able to find how to derive the solutions that you have for the first equation. Using your guideline for the second equation, I'm still yielding a value for $b$ that is not consistent or sensical across a wide variety of cases. I'll edit the above post with more details of exactly what I'm doing soon, as I feel I must be missing something basic.

Comment: I just used the general formula for quadratics, and factored out the minus sign to get the imaginary unit.